# SVN Authz setting permissions

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I am currently trying to set up my repository to prevent access from a specific user from accessing a directory of a project.  I have simplified my issue in a virtual machine that is having the same issue.  I have created a repository in /home/svn/ called myproject.  I am successfully able to add files, check in / out.  I am trying to prevent the user Ted (a contractor) from accessing the employee only directory.

**/home/svn/myproject/conf/svnserve.conf:**

```
[general]
# anon-access = read
# auth-access = write
# password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz

# realm = My First Repository

[sasl]
```

**/home/svn/myproject/conf/authz:**

```
[aliases]

[groups]
contractors = Ted
employees = Chris, John

[myproject:/private/]
@employees = rw
@contractors = 
* =
```

When Ted checks out the repository he retrieves all the files:

```
Ted@test-VirtualBox:~$ svn co file:///home/svn/myproject/
A    myproject/private
A    myproject/private/examplePrivate.dat
A    myproject/emptyDir
A    myproject/emptyDir/test
A    myproject/sample
Checked out revision 2.
```

- SVN version 1.6.17
- Ubuntu 12.04.2
- Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

Is this issue caused by checking out by file:/// or am I missing something in the configuration?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. There is no server/authentication process in between, other then file-permissions on the svn directory. If they can read it, they can check it out. So, you may want to work at that level: give the employees & contractors system accounts different groups on the server, or use `svnserve` / `apache` et al. to play svn server, denying the users all _direct_ file access.

Comment: I was under the impression since I set Ted in the contractors group and I have it where contractors should not have access to myproject:/private/ that when he checks out the repository he should not get any files in private.

If Ted doesn't have (read) file access to /home/svn/myproject/ then he isn't able checkout that repo.

Comment: SVN groups are not the users groups on the OS. Think about it: if I can `cat /path/to/some/file/in/the/repo` as Ted, I can make a checkout if those are svnserver files. Any check from the `svn` client would be _voluntary_, and easy to circumvent by disabling it in the source code & compiling my own svn binary which wouldn't require authentication. The only thing enforcing anything here with the `file:///` option are file permissions on your HD.

Comment: Ok, so i have added all users for the repository to a group, changed file permissions of the repository and chown'd it.  switched from file:/// to svn+repos//.  Now everything is working, thanks Wrikken for the help.